# Redirect with anchor in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, anchor

On session time out I redirect to an error page with a QueryString containing the previous URL including a hash bookmark. But in IE 8 & 9 the window.location.hash part is not available after a redirect.

e.g.
SessionTimedOut?returnUrl=mylastpage#bookmark5

The bookmark5 hash either does not appear in IE after a redirect or oddly it cannot be read window.location.hash returns null.

It works in FF & Chrome and the bookmark can be read if I don't redirect beforehand..

ta

Comment: which javascript method do you use, to redirect ?

Comment: Actually there is an even clearer way of seeing this problem..

Click a link with a bookmark in an email with IE as your default browser. The link is opened but the bookmark hash is lost. I think there is nothing I can do to solve this.

Comment: sorry I didn't address your question just now, I am using asp.net and so the framework redirects to login if session expires, but I think this is general problem with ie. it can be partiality solved with cookies during a session but not when the user first visits the site e.g. from an email link or favorite.